# sql join: Detect changes

Tags: sql, cockroachdb

Periodically, I want to compare a global sql table (called "resource") with a local backup one (called "region_db") to see if a field has been changed. The field I'm monitoring this way is called "state", and the primary key is called "id". Currently I'm doing

```
SELECT id, state FROM resource
```

Then manually going through the resulting rows in a loop. For each (id, state) tuple, I do

```
SELECT state FROM region_db WHERE id = id
```

And check if the state from the local region_db matches the one from the global resource db. I'm able to detect two cases this way: 1) when a new id is added to resource, and 2) when the state of an existing row changes.

However, I'm missing the case where a row is deleted from the resource table.

I'm thinking about using JOINs but not sure about how to efficiently distinguish between the three cases (modify existing, add new, and delete row from resource table) while minimizing the number of JOINs / DB operations.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `full join`:

```
select coalesce(r.id, reg.id) as id,
       (case when r.id is null then 'DELETED'
             when reg.id is null then 'CREATED'
             else 'UPDATED'
        end)
from resource r full join
     region_db reg
     on r.id = reg.id
where r.id is null or reg.id is null or r.state <> reg.state;  -- something changed
```

Comment: This is sort of complicated .. Could he just not use a `UNION ALL` and detect all rows that exist in one vs the other?

Comment: @Zak . . . This seems simpler to me than `union all`.

Comment: this is slick. Nice use of the case statement, the coalesce, and the outer join.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57915714/sql-delete-oldest-n-records-from-each-group @GordonLinoff Could you please take a look?

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH joined AS (
  SELECT
    region.state as 'region_state',
    resource.state as 'global_state'
  FROM
    resource
  INNER JOIN
    region_db
  ON
    resource.id = region_db.id
) SELECT * FROM joined WHERE region_state <> 'global_state';

;
```

This query will get you a table that reflects when the state of an existing row changes. If you do a `left join` instead of an `inner join` in the `with` query, you will get records that may have been added but not backed up yet to `region_db`. Like-wise, with a `right join`, you may get records that have been deleted but not propagated yet.

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `UNION ALL` that should tell you the differences in the tables --   basically checking for where `count(*) = 1` meaning where the rows don't match (because of the `GROUP BY`)

```
SELECT id,state
FROM (
    SELECT id, state FROM resource
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id,state FROM region_db
    ) tbl
GROUP BY id, state 
HAVING count(*) = 1 
ORDER BY id;
```