# sql: Delete oldest n records from each group

Tags: sql, cockroachdb

I'm using cockroachdb.
For each group (grouped by id field), if the number of records exceeds 1000, I want to delete the oldest however_many records so that the number of records equal 1000 after the deletion.

This is what I have so far:

```
(select id, count(*) - 1000 as num_delete
    from db.table
    group by id
    having count(*) > 1000)
```

Which gives me the ids for which records will be deleted, as well as the number of records I'll need to delete.

```
         id | num_delete  
+-----------+------------+
  n7ia6ryc  |        437
```

Is there a way, using one sql statement, that I can add to the sql query above so that those records are deleted?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this works in CockroachDB.  If you have a column that is unique, then you can do:

```
delete from t
    where t.unique_col < (select t2.unique_col
                          from t t2
                          where t2.id = t.id
                          order by t2.unique_col
                          fetch first 1 row only offset 99 rows
                         );
```

This finds the 100s value of "unique_col" for each `id` and then deletes all rows (with the same `id`) that have a smaller value.

If there are not 100 values, then the subquery returns `NULL` and nothing is deleted.

Comment: Could you explain what you did here?

Comment: Thanks, and just to make sure, what do you mean by 'unique column'?

Comment: Oh (got it), you meant all unique values? Like timestamp?

Comment: @Jobs . . . `timestamp` is probably good.  Something called `id` would normally be a candidate, but obviously that has duplicates.

Comment: Got it. One more thing: did you mean to say 1000 and 999 (vs 100 and 99)? Also, if I'm understanding it correctly, wouldn't this be the opposite of what I'm trying to do? Say there are 1014 records belonging to a given id group. I want to delete only 14 records and leave 1000 remaining, not delete 1000 and have only 14 remaining. Lastly Could you pls explain where the t2 came from? never seen the "from t t2" syntax before. Thanks.

Comment: @Jobs . . . It should be one less. With `offset`, the first row is at offset `0`.

Comment: Though this didn't work for CockroachDB, I eventually did something similar (comparing the less than). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact syntax for cockroachdb, but I saw that it has window functions. Just like my case on postgresql :

```
WITH cte1 AS (
  SELECT id, user_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY created DESC) AS rn
  FROM table1
)
DELETE FROM table1
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM cte1 WHERE rn > 1000);
```